# RESOLVED = RNA_boolean_set: CURVE_OT_draw.wait_for_input not found

Tags: python

On my blender2.78 linux64B I have always this traceback on terminal and i can't solve it and remove:
"RNA_boolean_set: CURVE_OT_draw.wait_for_input not found."

Someone know to resolve the problem, please?
When I make a search on addons files, I find nothing!

Comment: You just need to File > load factory settings

Comment: I have found with a new re-saved config file. In this file, Blender keep some time a shortcut's error of old addons!!!!

Comment: Not so easy! It's in terminal even after reload default start file.

Comment: I have the solution, the addon in charge is: Freehand Curve Drawings(Edit mode curve drawing) by Ideasman42